# Azure SQL Server labeling vs Masking

Tags: sql-server

If we label a column as part of 'Data Discovery & Classification' in SQL server, will it automatically do the masking or we have to separately mask it?

Comment: How are you "labelling" a column in sql server? masking requires definition of privileged and non privileged users, and clearly adding a label doesn't define this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server labeling is kind of a meta data, similar to extended properties. So, it does not automatically enable masking. [More on Data Discovery & Classification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-data-discovery-and-classification?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=t-sql#Overview)

You can have a code, which reads `sys.sensitivity_classifications` and accordingly enable masking for the columns.